# Creating nested arrays from database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some tables in my database that have relationships between them in different ways. Now I want to create nested arrays from these in PHP so that my array structure looks something like this:

```
 - Parent
  - id: 1
  - name: "ParentName1"
  - children: 
     - child
         -  cid: 1
         -  name: "ChildName1"
         -  movies: 
              - Movie
                 - mid: 1
                 - name: "MovieName1"
              - Movie
                 - mid: 2
                 - name: "MovieName2"
     - child
         -  cid: 2
         -  name: "ChildName2"
         -  movies: 
              - Movie
                 - mid: 3
                 - name: "MovieName3"
              - Movie
                 - mid: 1
                 - name: "MovieName1"
 - Parent
  - id: 2
  - name: "ParentName2"
  - children: 
     - child
         -  cid: 4
         -  name: "ChildName4"
         -  movies: 
              - Movie
                 - mid: 6
                 - name: "MovieName6"
              - Movie
                 - mid: 7
                 - name: "MovieName7"
      - child
         -  cid: 1
         -  name: "ChildName1"
         -  movies: 
              - Movie
                 - mid: 1
                 - name: "MovieName1"
              - Movie
                 - mid: 2
                 - name: "MovieName2"
```

I've created a query which concatenates all the children ids, names and movies into single lines separated with a ",". This works for ids and names but gets tricky with movies.

```
SELECT 
        parents.id AS parentId,
        parents.name AS parentName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(children.id) AS childrenIds,
        GROUP_CONCAT(children.name) AS childrenNames,
        GROUP_CONCAT(children.movies) AS childrenMovies
    FROM
        parents
    LEFT JOIN relationTable ON
        relationTable.pid = parent.id
    LEFT JOIN children ON
        children.id = relationTable.child.id
    LEFT JOIN moviesRelatonTable ON
        moviesRelatonTable.personId = children.id
    GROUP BY 
        parents.id
```

I guess I could only query the parents and then in PHP loop over each one and get the children. But I feel that wouldn't be great for performance.

---

Is there a better way I can query this or should I go with the loops in PHP?

Comment: That's a tree structure, so maybe XML makes more sense. Or even Json.

Comment: Yes, it will be converted to JSON. But I need to get the data from the database somehow.

Answer (score -1):

If you're always pulling the full list out of the db, you could save the json as a file after processing once. On each request check file save date and last updatedate in db, and if the json file is up to date don't even bother with pulling it all out of the db, just use the file. If the file is not up to date, create it from the db and save it again.  That will help with the performance problem and then you don't have to worry so much about the subquery performance. You would need to use the functions `file_exists` and `filemtime`.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question on how to create a nested array from a database.

Comment: You can't create a nested array from a database directly. Database only spits out rowdata like an Excel file. You have to do nested queries like you suggested. This just tells you how to avoid having to do the nested query for every request.